# MySQL Select Rows starting from row meeting condition

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to run a MySQL query like so: when I select, it should select -all- rows starting from a row meeting a met condition.

For instance, we have the table 'colors':

```
ID | COLOR
-----------
1  | Green
2  | Blue
3  | Yellow
4  | Red
5  | White
6  | Black
7  | Brown
```

What I basically want to do is select all rows starting from the row with color = 'white'

So basically, the select results would be rows `5, 6, 7`.
I am not sure how syntax for such query would look like. I've tried doing some research but without any results, as far as I am aware, there's no `STARTING FROM` thing in MySQL, as I was thinking of something like `SELECT * FROM colors STARTING FROM color = 'white'` but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 2):

You do this by looking up the `id` for "white" and selecting from there.  Here is one method:

```
select c.*
from colors c
where c.id >= (select min(c2.id) from colors c2 where c2.color = 'white');
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `color` is unique:

```
   SELECT c2.*
     FROM colors c1
     JOIN colors c2
       ON c2.id>=c1.id
    WHERE c1.color='white'
```